# how to group CSS class settings

Tags: css

Is it possible to combine groups of class settings similar to how groups of settings can be combined for @media?  In other words, instead of doing this:

```
h1.subtitle,
h2.subtitle,
h3.subtitle,
h4.subtitle,
h5.subtitle,
h6.subtitle,
.h1.subtitle,
.h2.subtitle,
.h3.subtitle,
.h4.subtitle,
.h5.subtitle,
.h6.subtitle {
  margin-top:0;
}
```

I’d like to do something like this:

```
.subtitle {
  h1,
  h2,
  h3,
  h4,
  h5,
  h6,
  .h1,
  .h2,
  .h3,
  .h4,
  .h5,
  .h6 {
    margin-top:0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you really have to? Will there be any other elements that aren't h1-h6 (or the corresponding classes) with the class "subtitle" that would prevent you from just using `.subtitle`?

Comment: if using SCSS, you can do something like this http://jsfiddle.net/v6t2a/ As I understand you want to write the rules in an abbreviate way, so that's just the way you can using SCSS. Otherwise (the way you want) will give out a different result.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [less CSS](http://lesscss.org/) or [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) to do that as a pre compiler. But than it will generate it like this:

```
.subtitle h1 {} 
.subtitle h2 {}
...
```

Otherwise it is not possible.

Note: You don't have to use the type in front of a class.

Comment: I thought of using SCSS here, but this result is of course not what the OP wants (he wants `h1.subtitle, ...`), so even SCSS can't solve it?

Answer (score 1):

With Sass or Less, you could do something like this

```
h1,
h2,
h3,
... {
 &.subtitle {
  margin-top:0;
 } 
}
```

Which would output to

```
h1.subtitle,
h2.subtitle,
h3.subtitle,
... {
  margin-top:0;
}
```